# Removing an Element on Certain Location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say the window's location is on `htt://stackoverflow.com/index.php`, I want to remove an element in the index page with jQuery. This is what I have and it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var location    =   window.location;
    var locQuery    =   /index/i;
    if (location.match(locQuery)) {
        $('.someClass').removeClass();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. You can't edit another website's pages.

Comment: No, but you can manipulate how your browser displays them, with JavaScript for example.

Comment: I'm not trying to manipulate Stack Overflow in any way, I'm just using it as an example.

Comment: How exactly are you running this code?? Are you using greasemonkey or something else to run the code from your browser?

Comment: Why don't you try an alert("i'm in the inner block"); inside the if block? Maybe the jquery line isn't even touched. Else check the javascript console in firefox for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. `window.location` is an object so the `.match` method couldn't match anything from the regex. I had to use the `.href` property of `window.location` to get a match.

```
var location       =    window.location.href;
var locQuery       =    /index/i;
if (location.match(locQuery)) {
    $('.someClass').remove();
}
```

I hope I use the right terms. I'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You are only removing it's class, so for example

```
<div class="someclass"></div>
```

will change into

```
<div></div>.
```

try

```
$('.someClass').remove();
```